# PHP export csv file with a particular lines ending

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file that I read and save as an output file using the following code :

CSV content :

```
10038,"Service, Inc.",loten,4u@att.net,9951,xxx,6321
10041,Roadsi deInc.,Kgel,gel1980@gmail.com,1101,xxx,7967
10042,Rang LLC,Resgers,resranger85@yahoo.com,2073,4611,xxx


<?php
    $csv_filename = "output.csv";
    $fp = fopen($csv_filename, "w");
    if (($handle = fopen(__DIR__.'/test.csv', "r")) !== FALSE && $fp) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $data_row = array(
                    $data[0],
                    $data[1],
                    $data[2],
                    $data[3],
                    $data[4],
                    $data[5]
            );
            fputcsv($fp, $data_row, "|");
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($fp);
```

the results I get is like the folowing :

```
10038|"Service, Inc."|loten|4u@att.net|9951|xxx
10041|"Roadsi deInc."|Kgel|gel1980@gmail.com|1101|xxx
10042|"Rang LLC"|Resgers|resranger85@yahoo.com|2073|4611
```

how can I remove the quotes that the fputcsv function added when there is a space in a string and how can I add a 0d0a ending to each line of the csv output?

Comment: RTFM? http://php.net/fgetcsv There's options you can use to  list separators and enclosure chars.

Comment: If I read it , if I had a solution I would not ask here

Comment: You should read http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php actually since you want to change the default enclosure. Your answer is there, right at the top.

Comment: I did add the folowing :  `while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",",'"')) !== FALSE) {` but the quotes are still there in the output file

Comment: what about the line ending with 0d0a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes are added by [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/function.fputcsv.php), try [fputs](http://php.net/manual/function.fputs.php) and [join](http://php.net/manual/function.join.php):

```
<?php
    $csv_filename = "output.csv";
    $fp = fopen($csv_filename, "w");
    if (($handle = fopen(__DIR__.'/test.csv', "r")) !== FALSE && $fp) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $data_row = array(
                    $data[0],
                    $data[1],
                    $data[2],
                    $data[3],
                    $data[4],
                    $data[5]
            );
            fputs($fp, join("|", $data_row)."\r\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Sorry I get a worng result :only one line  10038|"Service, Inc."|loten|4u@att.net|9951|xxx|" , quote added at the end also I had to  put : fputcsv($fp, $data_row, "|", '"'); otherwise fput shows an error

Comment: Updated, using fputs and join instead of fputcsv.